# .StartExecution is not a function

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-step-functions

I have created a lambda (so far so good).

Specifications:

- Has access to stepfunctions
- Runs smooth
- version: Node.js 14.x

But when I try to invoke a step function from my lambda like this:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var stepfunctions = new AWS.StepFunctions({apiVersion: '2016-11-23'});
const params = {
  "input": "{}",
  "name": srcKey,
  "stateMachineArn": process.env.STATE_MACHINE_ARN
};

return stepfunctions.StartExecution(params);
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> Response
> {
>   "errorType": "TypeError",
>   "errorMessage": "stepfunctions.StartExecution is not a function",
>   "trace": [
>     "TypeError: stepfunctions.StartExecution is not a function",
>     "    at /var/task/index.js:119:26",
>     "    at wrapper (/var/task/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:273:20)",
>     "    at Response.next (/var/task/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:4585:24)",
>     "    at Response.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:326:20)",
>     "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:369:18)",
>     "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
>     "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
>     "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)",
>     "    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
>     "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)"
>   ]
> }
> ```

Which makes no sense to me?

If I see this documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html
And even this one:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/StepFunctions.html#constructor-property

The function should be available there.

What am I missing / doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo...it's a lowercase `s`:

`startExecution` vs `StartExecution`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/StepFunctions.html#startExecution-property

Comment: Ah. My bad. It's written everywhere with a capital though (a). Thanks!